# Is there a characterization for discrete torsion-free, non divisible group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a characterization for a discrete torsion-free, non divisible group?

Comment: Well, it may be wishy-washy comment but such a group is **not** a direct product of some copies of the rationals $\,\Bbb Q\,$ ...I'm not sure whether this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by discrete in this context?